# Master Detail View With Segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, detailview

I'm Trying to learn how to do a detail view for my project .

I have a simple `tableView` with a simple `Array` data to fill it.

The Table View :

[TableView Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L48hH.jpg)

I designed a detail View as well, with static tableViewCells

Detail View example :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeFF4.jpg)

I'v Connected both with a segue :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Profile", sender: indexPath);

        }
```

I also connected all the labels and images with `Outlets` i want to change between each `cell` but i don't how to advance from here.

right now every `cell` shows the same thing but i want to change the `data` between rows . So i would like to change the `data` through the segue and create a master detail application like in my tableview. Can anybody help me ?

Am using Swift 2.3 and Xcode 8.1

Comment: I don't understand your problem and desired outcome well enough to help.

Comment: Im trying to create a master detail application like in my tableView

Comment: You could start by adding a screen shot of what you're seeing and then clarifying which example is your expected result and adding a bit more code around what you've already tried.

Comment: I didnt do much i just set the segue cause i dont know how to continue or how to send data or change it

Comment: Well, SO is for specific questions.  I have no idea what you want to do.  So my recommendation is if you're really stuck then google for some master-detail tutorials and walk through them until you get it.

Comment: I saw all the tutorials out there believe me :( still didnt understand how to change data between different rows through segue

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to pass dataSource element to the next viewController. So you can just pick it using `indexPath.row` and use `sender` parameter to set it in `prepareForSegue` method.

The code below assumes your dataSource is `self.users` array.

**Swift 3**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let user = self.users[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Profile", sender: user)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let segueId = segue.identifier? else { return }
    if segueId == "Profile" {
        guard let profileVC = segue.destination as? ProfileViewController else { return }
        profileVC.user = sender as? User
    }
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let user = self.users[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Profile", sender: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    guard let segueId = segue.identifier else { return }
    if segueId == "Profile" {
        guard let profileVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ProfileViewController else { return }
        profileVC.user = sender as? User
    }
}
```

**Edit**

> im trying to change data like al the labels you saw between rows like
>   for example shalvata will have a different data from light house and
>   so , change the labels and images and so on

It is still unclear for me what data you want to change exactly. Also I don't understand the language on your screenshots, but since you name the relationship as master-detail, I suppose the second screen is meant to show more info about the entity selected on the first screen.
If so, you should start from designing you model so that it contains all those fields you need on the second screen. Judging by the icons it would be something like

```
struct Person {
    var name: String?
    var image: UIImage?
    var age: Int?
    var address: String?
    var phone: String?
    var schedule: String?
    var music: String?
    var smoking: Bool?
    var car: String?
    var info: String?
    var hobby: String?
}
```

Note: Remove `?` for those fields which aren't optionals, i.e. always must be set for every entity (perhaps `name` field)

**Usage**

I don't known how and when you create your `Person` array, but basically there are two approaches:

1. Use a list of entities with all fields filled on `MasterVC` and just pass the selected person to the `DetailVC` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`
2. Use a list of entities with some basic data (name, address, image) required for `MasterVC` and fill the rest of the fields only when required (`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method)

In any case you'll get selected `person` in `DetailVC` and now everything you need is to use that data in `cellForRow` method, just as you did on `MasterVC`. Perhaps it would be a better option to use static TableViewController for Details screen.

Comment: Hey Again Alex thanks for helping :) im trying to change data like al the labels you saw between rows like for example shalvata will have a different data from light house and so , change the labels and images and so on

Comment: @adirbuilder I've provided more instructions for you to try. Hope that will help you.

Comment: Amazing answer. I am using static cells `TableVC` for the `DetailVC` and those entities are restaurants so the `DetailVC` is a profile for for each restaurant with more info rather than the first `tableView` with `DynamicCell`s that showed the street and the name

Comment: I will be able to test everything tomorrow night and i will start implementing what you are suggesting :)

Comment: Hey alex i'm trying to implement it right now but i'm encountering some errors. i'm using Swift 2.3

Comment: Hello again. Check the update, I've added Swift 2.3 version.

Comment: Hey :) , I think we should continue talking in chat cause i have some errors :P Cant create a room tho cause reputation :[

Comment: hey alex I'm trying to work on what you sent to me and now i have errors

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're trying to do does not involve segues at all.  You can change data of cells using the `cellForRow` method in your `tableViewController`.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow

For example

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "foo"
    return cell
}
```

If that sounds confusing to you then you should take a step back and do some tutorials then post specific questions on SO.

Comment: I dont want to customize the table view cell i want to do when i tap on a cell i will get open a new view and get more information and new UI about the cell - master detail . Now you understand ?

Comment: Then do what Alex said.

Comment: Yea but how i change data of labels in that "ProfileViewController"